# Is there a backup utility?

Tags: debian, backup

I am looking for a GUI backup utility to run on Debian 9.#, to be used from a standard user login, that will backup to a USB drive without having permissions issues with the USB drive?

I have done extensive google searches without success.

Comment: What's wrong with `tar`?

Answer (score 1):

How about [Déjà-Dup](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/deja-dup), which is Ubuntu's standard and exists for Debian 9...

Déjà Dup is a simple backup tool. It hides the complexity of backing up the Right Way (encrypted, off-site, and regular) and uses duplicity as the backend.

Features:

- Support for local, remote, or cloud backup locations, such as Amazon S3
  or Rackspace Cloud Files
- Securely encrypts and compresses your data
- Incrementally backs up, letting you restore from any particular backup
- Schedules regular backups
- Integrates well into your GNOME desktop
  [image]